# PHP refer user back to the same exact section of the previous page navigated

Tags: php, html, reference, header

I am using **`header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`** to return users to the previous page after running some processes.

I would like to return them to the exact same section of the previous page they were navigating, so they don't have to scroll down and look for it.

What is the best way to achieve this? I assume it would be something like referring to the id of the DIV they were navigating...?

Comment: You could possibly use an anchor and pass that anchor along to your PHP code. Then return your users with `header ('Location:'. $_SERVER [HTTP_REFERER].'#$anchor_name')`

Comment: Also, you could mark anchor in cookie using javascript and redirect as suggested